# Android Studio Git checkout is a mess

Tags: android, git, android-studio

I'm using my NAS server (debian) for git repos keeping to code from 2 PCs. It works great with Android Studio integrated tools if you first make identical copies of a project folder on each PC. However, if I try to create a project on one and push it to my Git server - I cannot seem to get it on the second PC in any usable form using the Android Studio's "Import project from version control" first screen option. The project files seem to be copied fine, but the project doesn't look right in the left panel (The only items in the Project tab's Android tree are my project name and the empty Java subfolder). Run/Build buttons are grayed out. Message to upgrade project to gradle pops up, even though the gradle file is in its place. I've checked all the project settings - looks right. What I'm doing wrong?

The studio is 2.1 on both PCs, Git works fine. I'm adding the root of Android tree to git (gitignore is stock). The only difference between PC's is the path to the workspace folder (root of all projects).